# Assembly Language instructions that do not change EFLAGS

Tags: assembly, x86, eflags

I am trying to compile a list of AL instructions that do not affect the EFLAGS register. So far I have:

```
1) mov 
2) push
3) pop
4) lea
5) inc and dec do not change the CF
```

I am looking for weird/exceptional cases

Comment: My 8088 book lists the following as not affecting FLAGS: call, cbw, cwd, esc, hlt, in, into, j*, lea, lods, loop*, mov, movs, nop, not, out, pop, push, ret, stos, wait :)

Comment: @Jim: I am surprised to see NOT in that list

Comment: So was I. But I thought you would be more surprised that someone had an 8088 book (copyright 1981)

Comment: You should just go through your processor manual and read the description of each instruction to see which ones affect flags. ia-32 has hundreds of instructions. It's rather presumptuous to think somebody is going to read through all of them for you.

Comment: @Raymond: I don't want to anyone to read through the entire manual. I was only looking for counter-intuitive cases like inc/dec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the excellent table of all x86 instructions - http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html

See its columns `modif f`, `def f`, etc.

Comment: The least obvious and most notable case is that NOT doesn't affect FLAGS, apparently [a design mistake by Stephen Morse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74341777/why-does-bitwise-not-dont-affect-the-zf-bit) when specifying the 8086 ISA.  All the other standard ALU instructions that date back to 8086 affect at least some FLAGS, except for LEA which is sort of special.

Comment: @PeterCordes I found this comment of yours to quote [in a blog post](https://pushbx.org/ecm/dokuwiki/blog/pushbx/2023/1017_early_mid_october_work) and noticed that you misspelled the name here, it is actually **Steve** Morse.

Comment: @ecm: His web site is https://stevemorse.org/8086/, but the name on the cover of his book is Stephen P. Morse.  Apparently he prefers using his nickname so I'll do that in future.  (Steve is a common nickname for Stephen.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the correction! I did think the domain name would be definitive.